# Postgresql 9.6 error with php7

Tags: database, postgresql, php-7

I've set DB-postgresql 9.6 and php7 (in open server). In general error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20cyU.png)

[image]

As i understand problem with version php. because postgresql works with php 5.5

How i can correct this? In advance thank you.

Comment: This is seems to be a simple name declaration error linked to php7 evolution. And yes, nothing appears to be a PostgreSQL problem. You need to show us more code to point the exact problem.

Comment: What should i show? Basic settings in open server(recently downloaded).
And i wrote 127.0.0.1/openserver/phpPgAdmin

Comment: It seems that your Misc.php file line 8 have a method with the same name of it's class and you can't do this any more in php7, so you need to correct this error. Then your script should work again.

Comment: Thank you :) Working!  Simple delete function

Comment: But now new similar error in every page. Too long i'll edit every error..
https://imgur.com/a/n7Dd4